# Azure DevOps - how to update 'Not set' permission state for security groups in repositories using Azure cli or rest api

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

**Question** : How can I update the permission state from allow to 'Not set' for a security group from All repositories settings in a project using azure cli or rest API. In this case I would like to update the permission state of Create branch from 'Allow' to 'Not set' the Contributors group.

I know how to update as allow or Deny using the below call but not sure how to reset to 'Not set'

```
        az devops security permission update `
        --org "https://dev.azure.com/$orgname/" `
        --id $namespaceId `
        --subject $subject `
        --token "repoV2/$projectid" `
        --allow-bit $PermissionBit `
        --merge true
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of below CLI command to update the permission state from Allow to **'Not set'** for a security group:

```bash
az devops security permission reset --id
                                    --permission-bit
                                    --subject
                                    --token
                                    [--detect {false, true}]
                                    [--org]
```

Initially, Create branch permission is set to **`Allow`** for my **Contributors** group like below:

[image]

To change that to **'Not set'**, I ran below CLI command and got **response** like this:

```bash
az devops security permission reset --id $namespaceId `
                                    --org "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" `
                                    --permission-bit $PermissionBit `
                                    --subject $subject `
                                    --token "repoV2/$projectid"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in DevOps Portal, permission changed to **"Not set"** successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[az devops security permission reset | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-security-permission-reset)

Comment: Sridevi - Thank you for the solution, I will give a try, meanwhile I also tried the cli command az devops security permission reset-all --id --subject --token   [--detect {false, true}] [--org]   [--yes] to reset all the permission, but it kept executing and never completed, have you tried reset-all command ?

Comment: Also, I was able to use az devops security permission reset-all finally !! . Your solution also helped me.